# run php file through an anchor with javascript/ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get, anchor

I need all of this to function the same way, but I need it to load so that the page stays on index.php while up.php is run... anyone have any ideas? thank you in advance for any help!

```
<div id="left">
<span class='up'><a href="up.php?key1=<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2 ;?>" class="" id="<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>" name="up"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
<?php echo $totalvotes1; ?><br />
</div>
```

Comment: yes I believe I do... but what would that look like here...?

Comment: instead of anchor tag, just put link. Onclick, fire ajax and get results/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this using jquery

```
$('.up a').bind('click', function(e) {           
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link

  //make ajax call
  $.ajax({
   'url' : url ,
   'type' : 'GET',
   'success' : function(data) {
   }
   });
});
```

Comment: will that still run the up.php script?

Comment: yep! please go thorugh some quick tutorials about ajax

Comment: And do not forget to update the total votes on the index.php... might be helpful to put the number into an element that can be manipulated on callback ;)

Comment: thank you! how do i get more reputation to be able to vote for your answer...?